# SQL Injection fixed but query is not working -Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I fixed Sql injection in IF section and because the number of parameter is different in IF and ELSE sections,I break down IF..ELSE into two function but unfortunately My queries not work is anybody have suggestion Please?

```
 if (prevContactSeq==null)
    {

        contactQuery.append("Insert into contacttable(");
        contactQuery.append("ContactSeq,ID,LastName,FirstName,ContactLabel,Phone1,Phone2)");
        contactQuery.append("Values("+ contactSeq+ "," + Id + ",'" + lastName + "','"+ firstName + "','WEB',"+ Long.parseLong(contactresult) + ","+ Long.parseLong(alternatecontactresult) + ")");
        //+ updateFields + " where id = " + tId;
        logClient.debug("Insert Query " + contactQuery.toString()); 
        System.out.println("RContact Insertion Query "+contactQuery.toString());
    }
    else
    {


        contactQuery.append("Update contacttable ");
        contactQuery.append(" Set phone1=" + Long.parseLong(contactresult) + ",");
        contactQuery.append(" phone2 =" + Long.parseLong(alternatecontactresult));
        contactQuery.append(" Where contactSeq="+ prevContactSeq);
        contactQuery.append(" And id=" + Id);

        System.out.println("Contact Update Query "+contactQuery.toString());
    }

    try{        
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = this.getJdbcTemplate();         
        return jdbcTemplate.update(contactQuery.toString());
    }catch(DataAccessException dae){
        dae.printStackTrace();
        //error in making the database update. return 0 to identify that the     database update failed
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I do this fixes but queries are not working  :

```
if (prevContactSeq == null) {



        update= insertContact(firstName,Id, contactresult,
                alternatecontactresult, contactSeq,lastName);
    }
    else
    {


        update= updateContact(Id, contactresult,
                alternatecontactresult, prevContactSeq);
    }
    return update;



}

private int updateContact(int Id,
        String contactresult, String alternatecontactresult,
        Integer prevContactSeq) {

    StringBuffer contactQuery =new StringBuffer();
    contactQuery.append("Update contacttable ");
    contactQuery.append(" Set phone1=Long.parseLong(?),");
    contactQuery.append(" phone2 =Long.parseLong(?)");
    contactQuery.append(" Where contactSeq=?");
    contactQuery.append(" And id=?");

    System.out.println("Contact Update Query "+contactQuery.toString());
    try{        
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = this.getJdbcTemplate();         
        return jdbcTemplate.update(contactQuery.toString(),  new Object[] {contactresult,alternatecontactresult,prevContactSeq,Id});
    }catch(DataAccessException dae){
        dae.printStackTrace();
        //error in making the database update. return 0 to identify that the database update failed
        return 0;
}
}

private int insertContact(String firstName, int Id,
        String contactresult, String alternatecontactresult,
        Integer contactSeq,String lastName) {
    StringBuffer contactQuery =new StringBuffer();
    contactQuery.append("Insert into contacttable(");
    contactQuery.append("ContactSeq,ID,LastName,FirstName,ContactLabel,Phone1,Phone2)");
    contactQuery.append("Values( ?,?,?,?,?,Long.parseLong(?),Long.parseLong(?)");
    logClient.debug("Insert Query " + contactQuery.toString()); 
    System.out.println("Contact Insertion Query "+contactQuery.toString());
    try{        
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = this.getJdbcTemplate();         
        return jdbcTemplate.update(contactQuery.toString(),  new Object[] {contactSeq,Id,lastName,firstName,"WEB",contactresult,alternatecontactresult});
    }catch(DataAccessException dae){
        dae.printStackTrace();
        //error in making the database update. return 0 to identify that the database update failed
        return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: SQL doesn't have any Long.parseLong() function. If contactResult (and other arguments) are supposed to be long values and not Strings, then they should be of type long. Use the appropriate type from the start, i.e. before calling these methods.

Comment: Thank you for your response. am i do a right job for fixing Sql injection by using prepared statement? Please advise. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing SQL injection but not injecting the parameters properly.

Your code needs to be changed as below,**ParseLong** should be used where we have value

```
StringBuffer contactQuery =new StringBuffer();
    contactQuery.append("Update contacttable ");
    contactQuery.append(" Set phone1=?,");
    contactQuery.append(" phone2 =?");
    contactQuery.append(" Where contactSeq=?");
    contactQuery.append(" And id=?");
```

and parameters passing dynamically should have a parse method like below

```
 return jdbcTemplate.update(contactQuery.toString(),  new Object[] {Long.parseLong(contactresult),Long.parseLong(alternatecontactresult),prevContactSeq,Id});
```

else part change

```
private int updateContact(int Id,
        String contactresult, String alternatecontactresult,
        Integer prevContactSeq) {

    StringBuffer contactQuery =new StringBuffer();
    contactQuery.append("Update contacttable ");
    contactQuery.append(" Set phone1=?,");
    contactQuery.append(" phone2 =?");
    contactQuery.append(" Where contactSeq=?");
    contactQuery.append(" And id=?");

    System.out.println("Contact Update Query "+contactQuery.toString());
    try{        
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = this.getJdbcTemplate();         
        return jdbcTemplate.update(contactQuery.toString(),  new Object[] {Long.parseLong(contactresult),Long.parseLong(alternatecontactresult),prevContactSeq,Id});
    }catch(DataAccessException dae){
        dae.printStackTrace();
        //error in making the database update. return 0 to identify that the database update failed
        return 0;
}
}
```

If you are not sure of value can be null, you can add null check before doing `Long.parseLong`

Comment: could you please give me your idea in Else section I have problem with this part . Thanks